# Cannot compile a statically linked Rust binary using docker due to zlib failure on M1 Mac

Tags: docker, rust, apple-m1

I'm trying to do some local dev to run some integration tests and need to compile a binary that's statically linked so I can use some C dependencies. This worked fine on my intel mac but I've been totally unable to create a useable image on my M1 mac.

### Cargo.toml

```toml
[dependencies]
serde = "1.0.136"
serde_json = "1.0.79"
rdkafka = { version = "0.28.0", features = ["cmake-build"]} # , "ssl", "gssapi-vendored"
tokio = { version = "1.17", features = ["rt-multi-thread", "macros"] }
meilisearch-sdk = "0.17.0"
futures = "0.3.21"
log = "0.4.16"
pretty_env_logger = "0.4.0"
async-trait = "0.1.53"
tonic = "0.7.2"
nats = "0.21.0"
prost = "0.10.4"
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
```

### Dockerfile

```docker
# Use clux/muslrust to compile the statically linked C-binaries for rdkafka
FROM docker.io/clux/muslrust:latest as build

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gcc-multilib g++ cmake libsasl2-dev build-essential linux-libc-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev -y
WORKDIR /usr/src

# Download the target for static linking & add rustfmt
RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl  && rustup component add rustfmt


# Compile and install the binary
COPY . .
RUN ln -s /bin/g++ /bin/musl-g++
RUN cargo install --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --path .
```

### Error:

```
Compiling tracing v0.1.37
#18 167.5 <jemalloc>: MADV_DONTNEED does not work (memset will be used instead)
#18 167.5 <jemalloc>: (This is the expected behaviour if you are running under QEMU)
#18 171.3 error: failed to run custom build command for `libz-sys v1.1.8`
#18 171.3 
#18 171.3 Caused by:
#18 171.3   process didn't exit successfully: `/usr/src/target/release/build/libz-sys-dc1598b5e3c2b6ab/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
#18 171.3   --- stdout
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=LIBZ_SYS_STATIC
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs
#18 171.3   TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-musl")
#18 171.3   OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
#18 171.3   HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
#18 171.3   CC_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
#18 171.3   CC_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CC
#18 171.3   TARGET_CC = None
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
#18 171.3   CC = Some("musl-gcc")
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
#18 171.3   CFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-musl = None
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl
#18 171.3   CFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_musl = None
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=TARGET_CFLAGS
#18 171.3   TARGET_CFLAGS = None
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
#18 171.3   CFLAGS = None
#18 171.3   cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
#18 171.3   CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
#18 171.3   DEBUG = Some("false")
#18 171.3   CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,llvm14-builtins-abi,sse,sse2")
```

Comment: I don't have a Mac, so I can't reproduce it anyway, but for the people that have on, it might be difficult without your source code. Please reduce your problem down to a [MRE] and post it here, in its entirety.